# node js schedule cron job to call express route every week

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I have a page that when you access it, it runs tests. I want my tests to run every week so Im trying to create a cron job that access my express route every week. Sort of like Im making a get request.

For testing sake I have a cron job that runs every 2 minutes:

```
//schedule job every 2 minutes
schedule.scheduleJob("*/2 * * * *", function () {
    console.log('inside cron function')
});

router.get('/my_page_route_name', ensureAuthenticated, async function(req, res){
    res.render('my_page_route_file', {
        layout: 'dashboard.handlebars',
        jsMain: 'my_page_route_js',
    });
});
```

If I go in my url to `http://localhost:1337/my_page_route_name` It goes inside the router.get request just fine. But Is there a way I can trigger my cron job to call the same route and render the page every 2 minutes?

I'm unsure of how to do this because the router.get function uses res.render, and I have no `res` variable in my cron job

{{ **EDIT** }}

My cron jobs works and triggers a POST request to my route:

```
    schedule.scheduleJob("*/10 * * * *", async function() {
        console.log('inside cron function');

        const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/my_page_route_name/", {
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            "method": "post",
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "username":"exvar",
                "password":"examplevar2"
            })
        });
    
    });
```

and i created an express route to receive the POST request;

```
router.post('/my_page_route_name', async function(req, res){
    

    res.render('my_page_route_name_html', {
        layout: 'dashboard.handlebars',
        jsMain: 'my_page_route_name_jsmain',
       
    });
})
```

If I make a request in postman I can see the posr route returns the webpage html, but no scripts have been run, for example I have `<script> document.querySelector('.breadcrumbs').append('[[ html loadded ]]') </script>` inside my html file that gets loaded, but the code doesnt seem to be ran in the response I recieve

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a route every 2 minutes?

Comment: eventually i will have it fetch the route every tuesday, for tesing I have it run every 2 minutes so I can see the results when I run it locally. My cron runs every 2 minutes and I can see the console.log on my local machine, im just trying to figure out how to fetch my route now yes

Comment: Use https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) package in node as http requests get pretty complicated quickly.

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

//schedule job every 2 minutes
schedule.scheduleJob("*/2 * * * *", async function() {
    const response = await fetch('https://yourdomain.tld/my_page_route_name');
    const body = await response.json();

    console.log('inside cron function', body);
});

router.get('/my_page_route_name', ensureAuthenticated, async function(req, res){
    res.render('my_page_route_file', {
        layout: 'dashboard.handlebars',
        jsMain: 'my_page_route_js',
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, fetch works but doesnt seem to run any scripts on the page? For example, I added `<script>
    document.querySelector('.breadcrumbs').append('[[ html loadded ]]')
    </script>` to my html file, If I load the url in my browser normally I can see the text on the page. My cron job fetches the webpage with a POST request, which hits an express POST route I created, and it returns the html contents of the page but without my script tag having run, since I can see my text is not inserted in the response (updating my question rn)

Comment: I'm confused. Are you hoping the server executes your js? What is the response from fetch you're looking for here?

Comment: Yes I am looking for my response to execute some js. When I visit the url in my browser locally it executes js to query for values to display in the webpage. if values are broken it sends an alert email. So i was trying to have my page be visited every day by a cron job, which runs the js normally as if someone visited the page

Comment: That is not how servers and browsers work tho. The server can't execute the browser unless do SSR. Maybe use https://playwright.dev ???